# How to alt-tab to the last focused window of an application in GNOME without all the other windows of that application appearing on top?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, fedora, gnome, alt-tab

I have multiple windows of many applications opened. I want to switch between one window of one application and one window of another application very frequently. If I press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>, all windows of the application I switched to appear above the window of the application that I was on. If I do not want the other windows (of the application that I switched to) to appear on top, I have to press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> <kbd>`</kbd>, where <kbd>A</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> <kbd>C</kbd> ... means that <kbd>B</kbd>, <kbd>C</kbd>, ... are pressed one-by-one while holding <kbd>A</kbd>. I want that to be the default alt-tab behaviour (i.e., only the window I am switching to appears on top) because I rarely need all windows of some application to appear on top. I like the window grouping done by GNOME (i.e., <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd> to switch between windows of the same application), so I do not want to disable it.

One way to achieve what I want would be to map <kbd>Alt</kbd> + [<kbd>Tab</kbd>]<sub>n</sub> to <kbd>Alt</kbd> + [<kbd>Tab</kbd>]<sub>n</sub> <kbd>`</kbd>, where [<kbd>key</kbd>]<sub>n</sub> refers to pressing <kbd>key</kbd> n times, and leave <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> + [<kbd>Tab</kbd>]<sub>n</sub> unchanged for when I need to have all windows (of the application I am switching to) to appear above the window of the application that I was on, but I can't find a way to map one key-sequence to another. (<kbd>Alt</kbd> + [<kbd>Tab</kbd>]<sub>n</sub> <kbd>`</kbd> <kbd>`</kbd> will then do what <kbd>Alt</kbd> + [<kbd>Tab</kbd>]<sub>n</sub> <kbd>`</kbd> <kbd>`</kbd> <kbd>`</kbd> does by default, but that is fine.)

---

Fedora Linux 35 (Workstation Edition), GNOME Version 41.3, Wayland.